# Rails sending HTTP status code without status message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, nginx, unicorn, puma

I have a basic JSON error responder:

```
format.json { render json: errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

In **development**, running **Puma**, I get back:

> Status Code: 422 Unprocessable Entity

In **production**, running **Unicorn**, I get back:

> Status Code: 422

Can anyone think of a reason that the message would be missing?

Comment: I guess it depends on web server and not on Rails

Comment: Note that HTTP/2 doesn't have reason phrases anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rails sending HTTP status code without status message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159497/rails-sending-http-status-code-without-status-message/50162284#comment87339287_50159497)

is the correct answer in this case.

Once I switched on the 'Protocol' column in Chrome Dev Tools, I was able to see that I was using HTTP/2, which would explain the lack of reason phrases.

[image: toggle protocol column]

[image: h2]

Thank you [Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke).

Answer (score 0):

It is server and http version related. It will differ from your local and production servers.